# Why can I not change Particle System settings anymore?

Tags: particles

I'm kind of new to Blender, so this might be a really easy question to solve - I just couldn't find anything on the internet so far.

I created a particle system and already changed the settings to how I wanted them to be.
Now I want to change the lifetime of the particles (make it longer) but I can't figure out how. When I try to do it how I did it the first time, it doesn't work because the setting panel seems to be 'blocked' or so (see picture).

[image: ![Sorry for the bad quality - I hope it still helps!]

When I select the Particle Setting specifically, Blender tells me that it is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have baked data. Simply press the *Free Bake* button under the *Cache* section, and you'll be able to edit your settings; you will have to re-bake, though.